# Employing comparative forms without explicit comparison

Tags: comparisons

To highlight our company's benefits, we write short statements like "**3 times less rate**" or "**3 times lower rate**". Are these correct? Or do such forms require comparison to something else—for instance, "lower *than standard rate*"?

Similarly, if we use the phrase "[a competitor] spends n dollars, we spend **half as much**", can we end on *half as much* without appending a second 'as' phrase?

Comment: It would help if we could see the entire sentences, and preferably one or two from each side.

Comment: Good day, Cindy. May I suggest that you are more likely to receive a useful answer if you a) tidy up your syntax, orthography, and punctuation, and b) indicate what efforts you have made to answer your questions from the usual reference works, and what ambiguities or uncertainties remain? I'll take a stab at a) for you, but the community will probably want your own report respecting b).

Comment: The title of your question and the body do not seem to ask quite the same thing. You may want to edit to clarify.

Comment: Good day, StoneyB, I am thankful to you for correcting my question. It obviously looks much better now :-)

Comment: @StoneyB The edit is what caused the confusion -- OP's original seems to be right.

Comment: @Kris  You're quite possibly right. What OP seemed to me to be asking was whether the comparative forms "3 times less" and "3 times lower" required a 'complement' -- "3 times less than X"; the error which your answer corrects was not a part of her question. But I'm not wedded to my edit--feel free to make your own.

Answer (score 2):

Kris answered the first half. Let me answer your final question. "Company X charges $1000, we charge half as much!" is fine. The obvious meaning in context is that you charge half as much as Company X. You could say, "we charge half as much as Company X" or "we charge half as much as they do", but it's not necessary. If you mentioned several other charges before so that it could be ambiguous, then you might need to clarify. Like, "The average charge is $100. Company X boasts that they charge only $80. But we charge half as much!" Now it's not clear if you mean half of $100 or half of $80.

Answer (score 1):

*"3 times less rate" or " 3 times lower rate"*
is to be avoided in any case. Remember, *times* implies multiplication, not division. It should not be used in cases of reduction. It seems to be so common (?mistake) these days that people have almost accepted it and presume to be correct.

*half as much* is a different matter and is fine, with the *as*, which cannot be omitted, because that could mean half-a-dollar, not half of *n*.

Comment: Good day, Kris. Thank you for your answer. Could you advice me then  how "3 times less rate" or " 3 times lower rate" should be paraphrased if we talk about reduction?

Comment: And may I clarify. Do you mean I should always add "as" phrase after "half as much"? for example "half as much as a competitor do"

Comment: If you so intend, you could say *a third of the rate*. In a situation where there is any comparison (obvious here), you will need the *as* phrase. The sentence structure is such here. Other instances are possible where the phrase can be safely omitted.

Comment: Thank you very much! Could you kindly give me some examples of instances where such phrase you say can be omitted?

Comment: +1 for your objection to "3 times less"

Comment: Of course in marketing literature, you may WANT to be vague about what you are comparing to. I've seen lots of ads that say things like "20% off!" 20% off of what? 20% off the manufacturer's suggested price? Off the average price of all your competitors? Off of what you charged last week? Off of your theoretical "regular price" that you never actually charge but just use as a baseline so you can boast about your discount? Etc etc.

Comment: thank you! then could we say that it will be justified if in marketing  literature  we will write "3 times less rate" or " 3 times lower rate" or it will be considered like a mistake?